# Meaning of "pachongón"

Tags: significado, palabras-raras

I cannot find a translation for *pachongón*. I have conducted a web search, the extent of my resources on a Sunday night, and haven't had any luck.

The contextual sentence is from a recent issue of People en Español.

> Tú podrás ser parte del pachangón de “Los 100 más bellos."

Comment: The closest I can find is _[pachangón](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=pachang%C3%B3n)_, meaning _[pachanga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ROsZqkH), fiesta_. Based on the context, could this be the word you are looking for? Remember, if you add a context to the question you will get better answers.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Maybe a sentence using that word?

Comment: Based on the contextual sentence I've added, I'm thinking the meaning is closest to "fiesta."  It was obvious to me what they were trying to say, but I needed confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Google search for the word](https://www.google.es/search?q=pachong%C3%B3n) turns out just two results:

- `Yo estoy ya lista fresquita y bien arregladita lista para el pachongón`, where it is used in the sense pointed to by CarlosAlejo's comment: **a degradation of** [***pachangón***](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=pachang%C3%B3n) as superlative of *pachanga*. Actually, the term *pachangón* is correctly used later in that text to talk about the same event.
- `A cual más gordito, mas tranquilo y mas "croquetoso" que ya con oir mi voz me hacen la rosca en la cuna ..... sin duda han salido al pachongón del padre`, where it seems to be used as **superlative of** [***pachón***](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=pach%C3%B3n).

Anyways, it doesn't seem to be an extended word, nor one recognized by any dictionary.

If you need a translation, based on context you could use "big party" for the first scenario. The second scenario is trickier; you could maybe use "dull", "plump"...

Comment: For big party, one could say *blow-out*.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it means just 'party'.

Like: you can be part of the party